# CDF of Brownian Motion

Tags: probability, integration, normal-distribution, brownian-motion

Let $a$ be fixed. I am trying to show $P(B_t\le t-a)=\frac{\int_{\infty}^a \exp(-x^2/(2(t-a)^2))}{\sqrt{2\pi}(t-a)}dx $ tends to 1 as $t\to \infty.$

[Mathematica Calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4S7Lv.png)

However, I am getting that the integral tends to about .84 https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F2(1%2B+Erf(1%2Fsqrt2), but shouldn't the limit tend to  1 since Brownian motion is almost surely finite?

Comment: The Mathematica result your image shows is correct. That is the exact transformation between the common notations of Erf$(z)$ and standard normal CDF. You might want to elaborate how you get the 1.05 numeric value.

Comment: Sorry, I'm getting about .84. Shouldn't the limit tend to 1 since Brownian motion is almost surely finite? I got the number by plugging in the mathematica result into wolfram alpha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability $P(B_t\le t-a)$ (for a standard Brownian motion $B$) is equal to $
\Phi(\sqrt{t}-at^{-1/2})$. This is not the same as the integral you have written down. The latter is $P(B_{t-a}\le a)$, which is in turn equal to $\Phi(a/(t-a))$, at least for $t>a$..